# Why does this print only 0?

Tags: c, hex, unions

New to C, I've been trying to convert a hex input with this code. The input argv[1] I've been giving it is 0xabcd123. It has only given me 0 outputs. I have also tried using atoi as well as varying the types of outputs. Why does it only print 0? Here is the code, thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef union{ 
    double num; 
    float f; 
} U;
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{   

U u;
u.num = strtod(argv[1], NULL);
    printf("%e\n", u.f);
return 0;
}
```

result is platform dependent!

Comment: Hint: What does the "d" in `strtod()` stand for?

Comment: You're converting the string to a `double` when the only values in the union are a `int` or a `float`.

Comment: also have tried printing as double and casting to double etc. all with 0 output

Comment: I think the result you're getting is platform-dependent.  I tested some possibilities on ideone.com and got no zero results.  Perhaps the width of those types are different on your system.  Try this: http://ideone.com/3BaMWc -- it's also just possible that for whatever reason your `strtod` doesn't handle binary floating points.  What compiler are you using?

Comment: YES, I think you are right. I have ran it unix and it works fine. My machine is windows 64 bit. How would the platform change this?

Comment: @user3050397 Check the size of each type on your system.  You could also try padding your union and see if that changes anything.  Add a member `char padding[16]`, and when you define the variable, initialise it to all zeros: `U u = {0};`

Comment: This code causes *undefined behaviour* by aliasing a `double`  as a `float`. The C standard lists the various types which may safely be aliased, and this case is not one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe its returning 0 on one system because of byte order. when you write to the value as a double but then read it as a float, you may be reading the top or bottom half of the double, depending on the architecture. on one system it's the empty top half of the double, on another its the bottom half which contains value.

either way, with a union, you should never expect to write any value as one type, and read back as another and get reliable results. as you have discovered :) unions aren't magic type converters, they simply allow you to save space when you know you have one type of value at a time.

Comment: I have to agree that a union might not have been the best choice for this! I have tried other types other than double and made sure to try to match the type I want to print with the one in the union but without any luck.

Comment: setting it as u.num and then reading it as u.f is never going to work (properly), regardless of what % symbol you use in the printf. by the time it's read as u.f, the value is wrong. why do you even have that union? if you want to convert a double to a float, you simply cast it from the double. eg. float f = (float)u.num;

Answer (score -1):

`num` is declared as `int`. So `printf("%d", u.num)` or `double num`

Comment: Oops. %d -> 180146467, and double num -> 1.801465e+08. Thats the result in my computer. Maybe you can post your new code again?

Comment: actually I had a friend run the same code and it seems to work for him. We are both using gcc. I dont really see why it doesnt work

Comment: Oh, sorry if my post is misleading. I mean either using %d to print out num (but keep `int num`) or change to `double num` and keep %e or %f

Answer (score -1):

- First, please kindly reformat your code so that everyone can read it easily.
- Second, the type of your `u.num` is `double`, so utilize `%f` or `%lf` instead of `%d`
- Third, as shown in this codepad http://codepad.org/JSSJEKOn, your code is correct and it must obviously print the expected result. So I think that the error is not here but somewhere else in your source file. Please give us more information

Comment: Just because something appears to work on one system, does not mean it is correct.